# What does the Drift attribute represent exactly?

Tags: driver-san-francisco

I have been trying to get a feel for what high or low Drift might mean for controls. I'm still unsure.

- Does high Drift mean the car sticks to the road less, allowing easier drifting?
- Does high Drift mean the car, on the contrary, sticks to the road?
- Assuming high Drift means no adherence... does low Drift mean high adherence? Experience seems to prove otherwise: most basic cars have all low values and yet start drifting if you take too-tight turns.
- Could it be strictly related to dirt roads? I've noticed cars with high Drift are sometimes also "rally" type cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drift attribute seems to refer to how well a car will keep drifting once it starts drifting. A starter car has low traction, but that doesn't mean you can drift for hundreds of feet in it - you'll either lose control completely or regain traction quickly. A drifty car, on the other hand, should start drifting as soon as you tap the handbrake and keep drifting through the whole turn, while still being controllable.

Comment: A very subtle different, but put like this it definitely makes sense and fits what I have experienced!

Comment: @leokhorn If you like it, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as the answer :)

Comment: I was waiting for potential alternate answers, just in case, before making my decision, sorry :). Since no one can top this (for good reason), there you go!